# differentiate between message came from facebook and facebook Chat Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

i'm using Messenger Chat Plugin from facebook in my website , my problem is i can not differentiate between messages came from facebook and messages from the plugin in my site web ?

is there a way to make a difference between those messages ?

Messenger plugin from the site web  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the plugin explains how you can differentiate these messages from others, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#detect

> **Detecting Message Origin**
>
> At times, it may be necessary to determine whether a user is engaging with your business using the customer chat plugin. To enable this, the Messenger Platform will include a `"source": "customer_chat_plugin"` property inside the message payload for all messages sent from the plugin

---

You can also use the `ref` parameter to pass in more detailed information, if needed, like the page the plugin was embedded on, or a reference to a specific user account on your site.